# How to change progress drawable of progress bar during program

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable

I'm trying to change progress bar inside color if value is close to max, basically default progress color is orange and i want to change it to green, how do i make it work?

Function:

```
public static void changeProgressColor(ProgressBar progressBar){
    int progress = progressBar.getProgress();
    if(progressBar.getProgress() >= 50 && progressBar.getProgress() <= 100){
        progressBar.setForeground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(progressBar.getContext(), R.drawable.progress_inside_green));
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBarEnergy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:progress="50" />
```

Drawable (green one, orange one is the same except inside color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:thicknessRatio="16" >
            <solid android:color="@color/progressOutside" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thicknessRatio="16">
                <solid android:color="@color/progressCloseLimit" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see that you want to change the progress bar's color to green when the progress value is bigger than 50. To do that you need to change the inside color of the progress bar, you need to modify the @color/progressCloseLimit in your progress bar drawable like this:

```
<resources>
    <color name="progressOutside">@color/your_color</color>
    <color name="progressInsideGreen">@color/your_color</color>
</resources>
```

Modify your progress bar drawable (@drawable/circular_progress_bar) to use the progressInsideGreen color when the progress is in the specified range. You can do this by creating different drawables for the inside and outside shapes and using a selector drawable to switch between them based on the progress value.
Here's an example of how your progress bar drawable (circular_progress_bar.xml) might look like:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Outside color -->
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:thicknessRatio="16" >
            <solid android:color="@color/progressOutside" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    
    <!-- Inside color -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <selector>
            <!-- When progress is between 50 and 100, use green color -->
            <item android:state_progress="true" android:state_after="50">
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:useLevel="true"
                    android:thicknessRatio="16">
                    <solid android:color="@color/progressInsideGreen" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Default, when progress is not in the specified range, use orange color -->
            <item>
                <shape
                    android:shape="ring"
                    android:useLevel="true"
                    android:thicknessRatio="16">
                    <solid android:color="@color/progressCloseLimit" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

With these changes, you don't need to programmatically change the progress bar's color; it will automatically change based on the progress value. Just make sure to define the appropriate colors in your colors.xml file.